# Как закрыть текущую вкладку без window.close()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, веб-программирование, asp

Всем привет, у нас проект на ASP Web Forms и раньше мы закрывали текущую вкладку с помощьюю редиректа на WindowCloser.html в котором содержался js script:

```
window.close();
```

Однако в один прекрасный день вкладки перестали закрываться данным способом, так как браузеры озаботились безопасностью и теперь при попытке вызова данного скрипта в консоли мы получаем следующее:
[image: предупреждение в консоли]

Вопрос: как теперь закрывать текущую вкладку, без использования всяких расширений, например с помощью code behind или Jquery(видел способ про установку дополнений(такой способ нам не подходит) для хрома и файрфокса, которые смогут закрывать текущую вкладку) и использование каких-то уязвимостей хрома для закрытия вкладки(они уже исправлены).
В интернете найти данную информацию не получилось, только один ответ на стаковерфлоу, который никаких реальных советов по закрытию вкладки не даёт.

Comment: Главная страница, открывающая окна должна иметь доступное дочернему окну API, вызов которого сообщит главному окну, что дочернее хочет закрыться https://stackoverflow.com/a/25099151/12888024 и главное окно его закроет. Но вопрос хороший, я бы с удовольствием посмотрел на ответ на него.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
let windowAnimanal = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");

windowAnimanal.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызывайте тот же `window.close();`, НО:

1. Вкладка, которую нужно закрыть должна открываться через `window.open();`
2. Не нужен редирект на сторонний файл. Вызывайте `window.close();` из той же вкладки, которую будете открывать через `window.open();`

Если такой вариант не подходит или невозможен ввиду архитектуры, то единственная альтернатива - менять бизнес-логику этой части проекта.